# Pandas - how to read a table from clipboard

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table from a web page.

```
                    <tr valign="top">
                            <td class="doprawej bezlewej">
                                AT00BUWOG001
                            </td>

                                <td class="doprawej">
                                    P
                                </td>
                                <td class="doprawej">

                                </td>

                            <td class="doprawej">
                                142
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                <b>BUWOG</b>
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                124&nbsp;184&nbsp;779
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                16&nbsp;019,84
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                12&nbsp;476,29
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                2018-07-31
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                H
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                1,28
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                14,00
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej bezprawej">
                                2,30
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td class="doprawej bezlewej">
                                PLBRSTM00015
                            </td>

                                <td class="doprawej">
                                    P
                                </td>
                                <td class="doprawej">
                                    LA
                                </td>

                            <td class="doprawej">
                                180
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                <b>CALATRAVA</b>
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                15&nbsp;000&nbsp;000
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                3,45
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                7,93
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                2017-03-31
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                H
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                0,44
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                0,00
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej bezprawej">
                                0,00
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

I tried pandas `read_clipboard()`
but the result I'm getting is data from a column ends up in different columns, because there are some empty columns in the table.

```
           ISIN Market Segment    ...             PBV    PE  Div Yield
0  PLNFI0600010      P      LA    ...      2018-12-31     H       0,14
1  PLNFI0800016      P     141    ...               H  0,55     160,00
2  PL11BTS00015      P     650    ...               J  9,44      22,60
3  PL4FNMD00013      P     641    ...               H  1,25       6,80
4  PLABCDT00014      R     612    ...               H  0,94       0,00
5  PLABMSD00015      P     411    ...            0,00  0,00       0,00
6  PLAB00000019      P     612    ...               H  0,39       5,10
7  PLACSA000014      P     541    ...               J  4,20      13,00
8  PLACTIN00018      P     612    ...               H  0,51       0,00
9  PLADVIV00015      P     720    ...               H  2,07       0,00
```

Can I set some attributes in the `read_clipboard()` so that a row of data always has the same length like in the HTML? and the data ends up in the right column?

Comment: You try the read_html() function in pandas? If i understand you can work.[https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html]

Comment: @tiagohbalves I did not try read_html, I can't use a link, as it is a page visible only after authentication. The HTML page itself is quite large, it crashed my computer when I tried to copy-paste the html directly to a variable in python.

Comment: I find this solutiyou, on you read a downloaded downloaded html file.  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056120/using-pandas-to-read-downloaded-html-file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) method and added `<table></table>` wrapper manually.

But you may use this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
html = "..."
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.prettify()
```

---

Here is what I tried:

```
html="""<table><tr valign="top">
                            <td class="doprawej bezlewej">
                                AT00BUWOG001
                            </td>

                                <td class="doprawej">
                                    P
                                </td>
                                <td class="doprawej">

                                </td>

                            <td class="doprawej">
                                142
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                <b>BUWOG</b>
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                124&nbsp;184&nbsp;779
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                16&nbsp;019,84
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                12&nbsp;476,29
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                2018-07-31
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                H
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                1,28
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                14,00
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej bezprawej">
                                2,30
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td class="doprawej bezlewej">
                                PLBRSTM00015
                            </td>

                                <td class="doprawej">
                                    P
                                </td>
                                <td class="doprawej">
                                    LA
                                </td>

                            <td class="doprawej">
                                180
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                <b>CALATRAVA</b>
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                15&nbsp;000&nbsp;000
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                3,45
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                7,93
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                2017-03-31
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                H
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                0,44
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej">
                                0,00
                            </td>
                            <td class="doprawej bezprawej">
                                0,00
                            </td>
                        </tr></table>"""

df= pd.read_html(html, header=None)[0]
print(df)
```

---

The output was:

```
             0  1    2    3          4            5          6          7   \
0  AT00BUWOG001  P  NaN  142      BUWOG  124 184 779  16 019,84  12 476,29   
1  PLBRSTM00015  P   LA  180  CALATRAVA   15 000 000        345        793   

           8  9    10    11   12  
0  2018-07-31  H  128  1400  230  
1  2017-03-31  H   44     0    0
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, I just have a problem with accessing the html

Comment: Great check @Mark  ✓

Answer (score 0):

In pandas [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/io/clipboards.py#L10-L76) the `read_clipboard()` method is just a convienince wraper for `read_csv()`, which means you can use all the arguments from `read_csv()` in your method call